# how to link two docs in different collections in firebase to update them together?

Tags: firebase

I'm working on a social media web app and i wanna add share post functionality. when the user adds a post, I add this post in the 'posts' collection in firebase firestore, and when another user shares it, I add the post in subcollection in user doc, but when I change something in the post in posts collection, the copy version in user subcollection didn't change, so i wanna make the original and shared version of the post linked together, so when I change one the other is changed too.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the following:

- A given post will only ever be changed in the `/posts` collection, not the copies in user subcollections
- A user's shared posts are only accessible to that user's friends
- A shared post is copied to the location `/profile/someUserId/sharedPosts`
- A shared post uses the same document ID when shared (e.g. `/posts/somePostId5` will be shared as `/profile/someUserId/sharedPosts/somePostId5`)

Because a user's shared posts have restricted access, you shouldn't be able to update the copied posts from the front end. The best option would be for the post's author to update the original post at `/posts/somePostId` and then copy this version to all the copies.

To do this securely, you would use a [Firebase Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions) that uses a [Cloud Firestore `onUpdate`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events#trigger_a_function_when_a_document_is_updated) trigger together with a [collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query) to find all the copies, and then use a [batched write](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes) to atomically update them all at the same time.

When `/posts/somePostId` is updated (the `onUpdate` trigger), do:

1. Get the edited post's ID
2. Perform a collection group query on `sharedPosts`, where the document's ID is equal to the post's ID (the best way for this to work would be to store `postID` inside the document).
3. If there are any results, start a new batched write object and get the post's new data ready for copying.
4. For each result, add a set operation to the batched write at that result's location, with the new post data.
5. Commit the batched write to make changes to the database

Note: If a user wants to edit a post that is not theirs, they should create a new post (at `/posts/someNewPostId`), based on the old post's data (at `/posts/somePostId`). This will allow the above process to work in the same fashion. Alternatively, you could have a suggested edits collection such as `/posts/somePostId/proposedEdits` that contains contributions from users who aren't the post author.

Read the linked documentation sections and have an attempt at writing the code. If you get stuck, and then edit your question with what your new problem is.

Comment: Great answer Sam! Thanks for helping fellow Firebase developers 